# Array count mismatch after updating it with setinterval JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am displaying a data from Object array. The length of array is 4.

```
var employees = [
    { name: "Santosh", age:25, emp_id:23 },
    { name: "jyoti", age:93, emp_id:97 },
    { name: "abhishe", age:99, emp_id:96 },
    { name: "Amir", age:77, emp_id:16 }
];
```

[image: 4 array items]

Now I am trying to increase the data from 4,5,6,7,8 like this in every 1 second. It work perfect as expected until,
I wanted to update the data when it reach to the position 5.

```
var employees = [
    { name: "Santosh", age:25, emp_id:23 },
    { name: "jyoti", age:93, emp_id:97 },
    { name: "abhishe", age:99, emp_id:96 },
    { name: "Amir", age:77, emp_id:16 }
];



var newemp = employees;

var i, text;
function update_array_with_time(){

    employees.push(employees[3]);//repeating this data

    text = "<ol id='newid'>";
    for(i=0; i<newemp.length; i++) {
        var newage = newemp[i].age.toString().split("").reverse().join(""); // reversing age    
        text+= "<li>"+newemp[i].name+"-"+newemp[i].emp_id + "-" + newage + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ol>";
    document.getElementById("list_emp").innerHTML = text;

    var len = employees.length;
    console.log(len);
    if(len === 5) {
        employees[5] = employees[0];
    } else if(len===8) {
        window.clearInterval(setIntv);
    }
}
var setIntv = setInterval(update_array_with_time, 1000);
```

Now if you see my console message where I have print the length of array, after 5 there is no 6 and the 6th and 7th item is added together. This is bugging me.

It should first add 6th and then 7th in their own time. Why doesn't it display at uniform time ?

[image: console error]

---

### update

With help of @guest271314 I have successfully display it in a sequence order but the data is flicking.
[https://embed.plnkr.co/Ms8M2JDsONkAUggyAY0e/](http://plunker%20code)

Comment: What is `newemp`?

Comment: its employees. I have updated the code. I am sorry I am really a bad coder. I don't know why I created another variable when I can use the same employees for getting length.

Comment: Well you add it without going over the logic of displaying it.... so the next iteration it adds the two?

Comment: No. I want to repeat same data for next 4 repeated array(total 8). So when the array length reach to 5 i want to update the array values. Its updating but it is flicking. you will be able to notice it only before clearing setinterval. Please see the bottom of my post. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `employees[5] = employees[0];` you are assigning `employees[5]` which is `undefined`. `.length` is 0-based, when `.length` is `5` to select last element of array use `4`, which should then increase `.length` of `employees` to `6`.

```
if (len === 5) {
    employees[4] = employees[0];
} else if(len===8) {
    window.clearInterval(setIntv);
}
```

---

> Overall the sequence is correct. but when you run the code for the
>   first time you see the no. 5 is updated with the data 'Amir' first and next timeinterval it automatically update to Santosh it is
>   flicking is there any possibilites to display Santosh at first
>   instance

Move `for` loop to after `if..else` statement.

```
if(len === 5) {
    employees[4] = employees[0];
} else if(len===8) {
    window.clearInterval(setIntv);      
}

text = "<ol id='newid'>";
for(i=0; i<newemp.length; i++) {
    var newage = newemp[i].age.toString().split("").reverse().join(""); 
    text+= "<li>"+newemp[i].name+"-"+newemp[i].emp_id + "-" + newage + "</li>";
}
text += "</ol>";
document.getElementById("list_emp").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Yes that does some help. but still the issue is the data is not displaying in uniform time. First it shows the regular repeating data and after that it update the data on that position. Any idea how do i update the data in their own time ?

Comment: I have created a plunk https://embed.plnkr.co/Ms8M2JDsONkAUggyAY0e/   No. 5 data is flicking. This is what I was trying to explain.

Comment: What is purpose of `employees.push(employees[3])`?

Comment: I am repeating that array with setInterval. And at 5 position I want to update the value of that array. Rest of other are same repeated array 'employees[3]'

Comment: The first time the function is called the `if` condition is met, before `setInterval` calls function again. At each `setInterval` call `employees.push(employees[3])` is called again. Not entirely certain what expected result is?

Comment: Can you give me any idea how to fixed that ? if I create a slice of that array then I will have to run the for loop again ?

Comment: What is expected result? Are you trying to call `employees.push(employees[3])` at each call to `update_array_with_time`?

Comment: In no. 5 first it display "Amir" and in next 1 sec it changes to "Santosh". why can't show "Santosh" instead of "Amir" before next update.

Comment: @Santosh Still not gathering what sequence you are expecting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131841/discussion-between-santosh-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

When you have 5 employees you run `employees[5]=employees[0]`. This essentially adds a sixth employee, as employees are counted from zero.

Comment: Yes, but any idea how do I make it part of the array so that it displays in uniform time set in setinterval function ? I want to change the array item in no. 5th position.

Comment: The 5th position is employees[4].

Comment: with the help of @guest271314 the value is updating but it is flicking https://embed.plnkr.co/Ms8M2JDsONkAUggyAY0e/  any idea to show that value at same time when position 5 is displayed ?